# Align Contents in Two Columns (SSRS)

Tags: sql, reporting-services, expression, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I am trying to display a report in SSRS as a table. I have three columns -Date, 5000 Brush, and 5000 Roller.  I am grouping the 2 columns brush and roller with the date column. I have one dataset and it returns job numbers which are specific for the 2 columns. I have used expressions to sort out which column displays which record.

Example expression I have used in "5000 Roller" column is

```
=Switch(Fields!MachineName.Value="TP5000", Fields!JobNum.Value)
```

The report display all data successfully but my problem is the 2 columns are not aligned.

Below is an example of the output of my report 
[image]

As you can see in the above image, the first 3 records are for the column "5000 brush" but the other records are for "5000 Roller", the problem is, records for "5000 roller" start from the 4th row of its column rather than from the 1st row.

Is there a solution to fix this issue?

Comment: SSRS will display a row in the table for each row returned from the database, and each row from your database appears to either belong to `Roller` or `Brush`, so you will only ever get one of `Roller` or `Brush` for any given row.

Comment: @DaleBurrell Thank for the response Dale. Is there a workaround to avoid this?

Comment: ! wouldn't call it a work around - this is normal behaviour for data display. You could create a query which has `Roller` & `Brush` in the same row... probably with a `pivot` or similar. Or you could just display `Roller` & `Brush` is completely separate tables.

Comment: @DaleBurrell I think I will be going with the Pivot option. Thanks Dale.

Comment: The question you have to ask yourself is: "Why should the numbers 152694 and 152102 be displayed in the same row?"